# PHP conditional statment inside a function

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to create function that takes two arguments one for the user input and the other a message for error. I initially have an associative array with the two input fields and the corresponding error.
When the function is submitted without any entry I get two similar output; I thought I would get 'test1' and 'test2'. I am passing different arguments each time but I get the same result. The code is below

```
$valid = TRUE;
    //$errors='';
    $errors=array('desc_error'=>'please enter valid description',
                  'title_error'=>'provide valid title','no_error'=>'',);
    function sanitizeText($input,$error){
        //$input;
        if($input!='')
        {
            $input= filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
            if($input==''){
                global $errors;
                $errors[$error];
                $valid=FALSE;
                return $errors[$error];
            }
            else{
                $input;
                echo 'test 1';
                return $input;
            }


        } 
        else if($input=='')
        {

            if($input==$_POST['desc'])
            {
                echo 'the description field is required<br/>';
                $valid=FALSE;
            }
            else{
                //
            }

        }

    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $title=sanitizeText($_POST['title'],'title_error');
        $desc=sanitizeText($_POST['desc'],'desc_error');


    }

?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Book Title:<input type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" value=""/></p>
     <p>Desc:<input type="text" name="desc" maxlength="100" value=""/></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You do realize that $valid isn't in the function's scope, right?

Comment: ok, scope is a bit confusing I will do the fix, but Still the part where I am having is on the last if else statment. I submit, twice function invoked with different arguments but still echo "test1".

Comment: where is 'test2' is echoed from script?
in else if condition of $input == '' you checked to whether desc is equal to $input i don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to validate form using php you can also user javascript to validate but to do it using php please refer following links.

http://myphpform.com/required-optional-fields.php

http://coredogs.com/lesson/form-and-php-validation-one-page

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-form.html?page=3

and

http://www.montanaprogrammer.com/php-web-programming/php-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense logic wise.  Firstly, you check if `$input` is an empty string, or is not, and then within that first check.. you again make the same exact check.  Since `if`s are evaluated in order, and input is not ever going to be an empty string, the first `if` will always execute.

Then, your first 'else'; it will only execute if the `$input` variable is an empty string..   I can sort of see what you're attempting to do, but it won't work as it is right now.  In order for it to work, it would have to look something like the below:

```
function sanitizeText($input,$error) {
    global $errors;
    global $valid;

    $input_val = filter_var($_POST[$input], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ($input_val != '') {
        $valid = TRUE;
        return $input;
    }
    else if ($input_val == '') {
        $valid = FALSE;
        echo $errors[$error].'<br />';
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $title=sanitizeText('title','title_error');
    $desc=sanitizeText('desc','desc_error');

}
```

If the input value is not an empty string, it will return the input value.   If it is, it will not return anything and will instead echo the appropriate error.